# Creating a VPN for communicating two different boards

Tags: ubuntu, networking, vpn, openvpn, ubuntu-20.04

Beforehand, I would like to say that I am not experienced in networking and would like to learn more regarding this.

I have two boards that have to send and receive ethernet packets to each other. Let's call them board 1 and board 2. Board 1 is connected to Ubuntu 1 and Board 2 is connected to Ubuntu 2. Both Ubuntu 1 and 2 are connected to a bigger network. The diagram below shows the topology of the network.

I want board 1 and 2 to be able to receive and send ethernet packets through Ubuntu 1 and 2. If possible, in layer 2 (Data Link Layer) not layer 3 (Network Layer). I have read TUN/TAP interfaces, but am still puzzled on how to implement this into my network. I have also read IP Forwarding (routing) but this uses layer 3. I want these boards to communicate through layer 2.

My final solution was creating a VPN server in Ubuntu 1 or 2 using OpenVPN. This also uses the TUN interface (layer 3), but I am hoping it can be replaced with a TAP interface. This is my current question. How do i switch to a TAP interface in OpenVPN?

If there are easier suggestions, instead of creating a VPN an such, I would love to hear it also. Thank you in advance for your help.

[image: Network Topology]

Comment: I see everything on the same layer 2 segment in this photo. Are the Ubuntu boxes dual-homed into the 192.168.1.0/24 network, and "the bigger network" another subnet? I would look at ZeroTier layer 2 bridging, also might be something you can do with VXLan, although I don't have enough info to tell what's best.

Comment: I have researched some more and I believe using VXLAN was the best option. But due to the insecure connection for VXLAN, I have decided not to use it and instead use OpenVPN. I am still in the process of making OpenVPN work in ethernet bridging mode.

Answer (score 1):

I have decided to use OpenVPN as the solution to my problem. Even though VXLAN is the most compatible and easiest solution, it lacks security measures and thus I decided to use OpenVPN.

OpenVPN allows ethernet bridging (layer 2) and this is enough for my purpose. It is slightly harder to configure and install compared to VXLAN.

Thank you to everyone who have commented and helped.